# mysql change auto_increment field from null to number of records

Tags: mysql

Hiii..

I had created one table in mysql...and inserted about 320 records in that table. Now I altered that table and added one `auto_increment` field. Now it is showing `null` value for that field in all records.

Guys please tell me trick to update all 320 record with 1 to 320 in that field.

```
update formData set ID = (select @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rank from formData t, (select @rownum := 0)r);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think below SQL useful to you.

```
SET @rank:=0;
UPDATE formData
SET ID=@rank:=@rank+1
```

Thank you.

Comment: it give me error as you can't specify target table 'formData' for update in from clause....I have updated my answer where i fired the same query you have given me...

Comment: I have one question sequence number is their in that table?

Comment: my auto_increment column name is 'id'

Comment: what is the name of previous auto_increment column  name? and what is the name of current auto_increment column name?

Comment: sir previously der was no auto_increment column later i added it by alter command....